# Difference between "import" and load (as "> :l ")

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, repl

Update: I am more confused.

If you follow the sequence below, you see that I

1. attempt to load Either.hs, and get a missing module error
2. attempt to load Monad.hs, and get a "one module loaded" happy message
3. attempt again to load Either.hs, and again get a missing module error
4. attempt to import Week04.Monad, and get no error or happy message, but "Week04.Monad" joins other modules before my Prelude prompt. So it sure *looks* like Week04.Monad is fully available.
5. attempt to load Either.hs and continue to get a missing module message, even though that module has been imported and is in my prompt.

So, still totally confused. If the repl cannot locate a module that has been loaded and imported, how can this error message be made to go away? Or does it mean nothing?

```
Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default> :l src/Week04/Either.hs

<no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: 
        Week04.Monad
Ok, two modules loaded.
Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default Week04.Either> :l src/Week04/Monad.hs
Ok, one module loaded.
Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default Week04.Monad> :l src/Week04/Either.hs

<no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: 
        Week04.Monad
Ok, two modules loaded.
Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default Week04.Either> import Week04.Monad
Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default Week04.Monad Week04.Either> :l src/Week04/Either.hs

<no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: 
        Week04.Monad
Ok, two modules loaded.
Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default Week04.Monad Week04.Either> 
Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default Week04.Monad Week04.Either>
```

======== Original Question ========

I'm pulling this from a comment thread on another question as it is getting long and merits a separate answer.

In the repl, typically if I enter (as an example)

> :l src/Week04/Either.hs

I was getting an error (that is fixed and is not the question here). Another helpful Pioneer suggested doing

> import Week04.Either

However, I get the following error with that

> ```
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default> import Week04.Either
> <no location info>: error:
>     Could not load module ‘Week04.Either’
>     It is a member of the hidden package ‘plutus-pioneer-program-week04-0.1.0.0’.
>     Perhaps you need to add ‘plutus-pioneer-program-week04’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default>
> ```

I suspect this is either a directory level problem or (more likely) a "compiled vs interpreted" issue but still new enough to be confused. Can anyone clarify exactly how such things should work?

Comment: Are you still "more confused" after my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least two things contributing to the confusion here.

> 1. attempt to load Either.hs, and get a missing module error

You don't actually get a missing module error. You get a warning that `Week04.Monad` is "not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules". So it warns that you may have problems in the cabal-file but the repl compiles and loads the modules `Week04.Monad` and `Week04.Either` just fine. So you get `Ok, two modules loaded`.

> 2. attempt to load Monad.hs, and get a "one module loaded" happy message

`Week04.Monad` has no dependencies so it loads without warning.

> 3. attempt again to load Either.hs, and again get a missing module error

Nothing has changed here so this step is exactly the same as step 1 and you get exactly the same result. Why steps 1 and 3 are the same is explained in the description of the `:load`-command:

> "All previously loaded modules, except package modules, are forgotten.
> The new set of modules is known as the target set. Note that :load can
> be used without any arguments to unload all the currently loaded
> modules and bindings.".

The documentation can be found from [GHCi commands](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html)

The main difference between `:load` and `import` is that `:load` sets the current context in the repl so that you can access the internals of the module that has been loaded as current context. With `import` you only get access to things that have been exported from the respective module.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I think what it boils down to is that GHCi is broken issuing an error message that is either unhelpful or unfixable. I have noticed that in other places, eg. "*** WARNING: /Users/jwb/.ghci is writable by someone else, IGNORING!
Suggested fix: execute 'chmod go-w /Users/jwb/.ghci'". Combined with plutus being new and not-yet-finished, me being new to Haskell, Haskell being difficult, and the entire linkage/reference/nesting structure feeling very opaque, I am feeling perpetually lost in a way I have never felt with any other language.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? I usually import packages (e.g. Control.Monad) and load local files (src/Week04/Either.hs).

https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/c87eb1e3-190b-4f64-ac1f-22ee5b998f0d/y

Comment: Unfortunately, no. See my update in the OP. I don't know how the repl can obviously "see" the module but also simultaneously can't see the module.

Comment: I couldn't find an explanation of what is going on. The warning message is misleading, adding the file to 'other-modules' results in a duplication error. Moreover `:show modules` shows that both modules have been successfully loaded. I get no warning if I do  `:l src/Week04/Either.hs src/Week04/Monad.hs`.